# Android Serialization using put/getSerializable

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to save the state of a class when the user rotates an android device.  I wanted to use the putSerializable and getSerializable functions to get and set the class in a android Bundle.  A simplified version of the class is shown below:

```
public class State implements Serializable
{
  public class Unit implements Serializable
  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9107072458243854482L;
    private String mName;
    private int mCount; 
  }

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2794811960095192070L;
  private ArrayList<Unit> mUnitArray = new ArrayList<Unit>(); 
}
```

I have an instance of the above class called mState and use the following to put it in and get it out of a Bundle.

```
myBundle.putSerializable("StateManager", mState);

mState = (State)myBundle.getSerializable("StateManager");
```

Is there any reason why this shouldn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not the answer to your question, but you can prevent the activity from restarting on rotation by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity tags in the manifest file. Maybe you don't want this, but maybe you do, worth the shot :)

Comment: Thanks @Niek, that's really helpful.  Many of my activities don't require a restart so that looks as though it should do the job.

Comment: @mibollma the arraylist mUnitArray does not get repopulated by the call to getSerializable.

Comment: Please, using andorid:configChanges is NOT a solution to you not being able to save state.  It just makes your problem more visible.  The user almost certainly *will* see the problem in other cases, such as if your app goes to the background and its process gets killed prior to them returning to it.  Also, what if the user plugs in a keyboard?  There is a new kind of input device, and thus a config change, and now your activity is restarted.  Or the screen size changes.  Or locale changes.  And on and on.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you want Unit to be non-static internal class? Non static intrnal class has always the outside object as implicit member and having an array of those inside an object that contains the array seems odd...

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think I ought to read up on my Java before getting too much further into this android project.   Coming from C++, a class declared within another class is fairly standard practice and it wouldn't be a problem to declare a std::vector<Units> as in the example above.  Thanks for input though.